# How to rename photo files using awk, such that they are named (and hence ordered) by "date taken"?

Tags: awk, metadata, filenames, photo

I have 3 groups of photos, from 3 different cameras (with time sychronised onboard all cameras) but with different naming schemes (*e.g.:* `IMG_3142.jpg`, `DCM_022.jpg`). I would like to rename every photo file with the following naming convention:

```
1_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss.jpg for earliest
2_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss.jpg for next earliest, and so on,
```

until we reach around `5000_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss.jpg` for the last one (*i.e.* the most recent)

I would like the `yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss` field to be replaced by the “date and time taken” value for when this photo was taken. Which is saved in the metadata/properties of each file.

I have seen **awk** used to carry out similar operations but I'm not familiar enough to know how to access the “time taken” metadata, etc.

Also, not that this should make a difference: my computer is a mac.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the online documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.  StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jhead` for this. The command is:

```
jhead -n%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S *.jpg
```

Make a **COPY** of your files first before running it! You can install `jhead` with `homebrew` using:

```
brew install jhead
```

Or, if you don't have `homebrew`, download [here](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) for OS X.

That will get you the date in the filename as you wish. The sequence number is a little more difficult. Try what I am suggesting above and, if you are happy with that, we can work on the sequence number maybe. Basically, you would run `jhead` again to set the file modification times of your files to match the time they were shot - then the files can be made to show up in the listing in date order and we can put your sequence number on the front.

So, to get the file's date set on the computer to match the time it was taken, do:

```
jhead -ft *.jpg
```

Now all the files will be dated on your computer to match the time the photos were taken. Then we need to whizz through them in a loop with our script adding in the sequence number:

```
#!/bin/bash
seq=1

# List files in order, oldest first
for f in $(ls -rt *jpg)
do
   # Work out new name
   new="$seq_$f"
   echo Rename $f as $new
   # Remove "#" from start of following command if things look good so the renaming is actually done
   # mv "$f" $new"
   ((seq++))
done
```

You would save that in your HOME directory as `renamer`, then you would go into Terminal and make the script executable like this:

```
chmod +x renamer
```

Then you need to go to where your photos are, say `Desktop\Photos`

```
cd "$HOME/Desktop/Photos"
```

and run the script

```
$HOME/renamer
```

That should do it.

By the way, I wonder how wise it is to use a simple sequence number at the start of your filenames because that will not make them come up in order when you look at them in Finder.

Think of file `20` i.e. `20_2015_02_03_11:45:52.jpg`. Now imagine that files starting with 100-199 will be listed BEFORE file 2o, also files 1000-1999 will also be listed before file 20 - because their leading `1`s come before file `20`'s leading `2`. So, you may want to name your files:

```
0001_...
0002_...
0003_...
...
0019_...
0020_...
```

then they will come up in sequential order in Finder. If you want that, use this script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
seq=1
for f in $(ls -rt *jpg)
do
   # Generate new name with zero-padded sequence number
   new=$(printf "%04d_$f" $seq)
   echo Rename $f as $new
   # Remove "#" from start of following command if things look good so the renaming is actually done
   # mv "$f" $new"
   ((seq++))
done
```